# Coordinates equipped with equivalences in other conventional (or unconventional) ways

Tags: coordinate-systems, equivalence-relations

I know coordinates with equivalences of the type :

**(a,b,c, ...) ~ (a+k, b+k, c+k, ...)**

**(a,b,c, ...) ~ (ak, bk, ck, ...)**

Does exist some other type of coordinates (and its geometry associated) that
make use of equivalences on some other way.

Once, I see a commentary by John Conway where it is mentioned something like

**(a,b,c, ...) ~ (ak+k, bk+k, ck+k, ...)**

Where **n** components are naturally put in **n-2** dimensions, but, it happens that I am unable
to find that reference in the internet (in the context of simplicial coordinates).

If the above is correct, exist some other ?